# Multiple http calls Not fetching data in angular for the first time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have a problem with fetching data from api by using http calls in angualr.
    The below is the code that gets called first on a button click.

```
$scope.loadMerchGroup = function(division){
            $scope._loadMerchGroup("A", division).then(function(data){
                $scope.merchGroup1Options=data;
                $scope.merchGroup1Optionscode=_.map($scope.merchGroup1Options, function(o) { return _.omit(o, 'description'); });

            });
            $scope._loadMerchGroup("B", division).then(function(data){
                $scope.merchGroup2Options=data;
                console.log("B")
                console.log(data)
                $scope.merchGroup2Optionscode=_.map($scope.merchGroup2Options, function(o) { return _.omit(o, 'description'); });
            });
            $scope._loadMerchGroup("C", division).then(function(data){
                $scope.merchGroup3Options=data;
                console.log("C")
                console.log(data)
                $scope.merchGroup3Optionscode=_.map($scope.merchGroup3Options, function(o) { return _.omit(o, 'description'); });
            });
            $scope._loadMerchGroup("D", division).then(function(data){
                $scope.merchGroup4Options=data;
                $scope.merchGroup4Optionscode=_.map($scope.merchGroup4Options, function(o) { return _.omit(o, 'description'); });
            });
            $scope._loadMerchGroup("E", division).then(function(data){
                $scope.merchGroup5Options=data;
                $scope.merchGroup5Optionscode=_.map($scope.merchGroup5Options, function(o) { return _.omit(o, 'description'); });
            });
            $scope._loadMerchGroup("F", division).then(function(data){
                $scope.merchGroup6Options=data;
                $scope.merchGroup6Optionscode=_.map($scope.merchGroup6Options, function(o) { return _.omit(o, 'description'); });
            });
            $scope._loadMerchGroup("G", division).then(function(data){
                $scope.merchGroup7Options=data;
                $scope.merchGroup7Optionscode=_.map($scope.merchGroup7Options, function(o) { return _.omit(o, 'description'); });
            });
            $scope._loadMerchGroup("H", division).then(function(data){
                $scope.merchGroup8Options=data;
                $scope.merchGroup8Optionscode=_.map($scope.merchGroup8Options, function(o) { return _.omit(o, 'description'); });
            });
            $scope._loadMerchGroup("I", division).then(function(data){
                $scope.merchGroup9Options=data;
                $scope.merchGroup9Optionscode=_.map($scope.merchGroup9Options, function(o) { return _.omit(o, 'description'); });
            });
            $scope._loadMerchGroup("J", division).then(function(data){
                $scope.merchGroup10Options=data;
                $scope.merchGroup10Optionscode=_.map($scope.merchGroup10Options, function(o) { return _.omit(o, 'description'); });
            });
            $scope._loadMerchGroup("K", division).then(function(data){
                $scope.merchGroup11Options=data;
                $scope.merchGroup11Optionscode=_.map($scope.merchGroup11Options, function(o) { return _.omit(o, 'description'); });
            });
            $scope._loadMerchGroup("L", division).then(function(data){
                $scope.merchGroup12Options=data;
                $scope.merchGroup12Optionscode=_.map($scope.merchGroup12Options, function(o) { return _.omit(o, 'description'); });
            });
            $scope._loadMerchGroup("M", division).then(function(data){
                $scope.merchGroup13Options=data;
                $scope.merchGroup13Optionscode=_.map($scope.merchGroup13Options, function(o) { return _.omit(o, 'description'); });
            });
        };
There after each _loadMerchGroup() will instantiate the below code.

$scope._loadMerchGroup = function(gtype, div){
            _url = $scope.getUri() + "MerchGroup/?groupType="+gtype+"&division="+div;
            var defer = $q.defer();
             console.log(div)
              console.log(gtype)
               console.log(_url)
            $scope.dataService(_url, "GET").then(function(data){
                defer.resolve(data);
            });
            return defer.promise;
        };
And after $scope.dataService() will be instantiated with the respective parameters passed.

$scope.dataService = function(_url, _method){
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $scope.getSetting();
            //_url = $scope.setting.api_url;

            $http({
                method: _method, url: _url, /*cache: $templateCache,*/ 
                headers: _headers
            }).
              then(function (response) {
                  defer.resolve(response.data);
              }, function (response) {
                  //$scope.handleError(response);
                  defer.reject(response)                 
              });
            return defer.promise;
        };
and then returns the promise and then back to original _loadMerchGroups.
```

But for every return of a call it is returning null data for the first time on a button click. but gets the data for the second time or third time.
Could some one suggest me a better method To fetch the data for the first click. This has became a mess for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `dataservice` definition inside controller? The main purpose of using service is re usability and you can inject your service into multiple controllers if needed. You can read about [Dependency injection here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_dependency_injection.htm). I have created a service and I have injected the service into the controller.

```
    .service('dataService', ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http){
            this.getData = function(_url, _method){
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: 'GET', url: _url
            }).
              then(function (response) {
                  defer.resolve(response.data);
              }, function (response) {
                  defer.reject(response)                 
              });
            return defer.promise;
        };                                                               
    }]);
```

Here is the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gilango/09wwg7ug/29/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry mate. It did not solve my problem. still facing the same issue. its unable to fetch data for the first time i click.

Comment: Do you get any console error? Make sure your first click hits all the function calls and http call.

Comment: Yes,it hits all the functions. problem in fetching data.